# Salesforce Flow Quick assign record is Created

Tags: visual-workflow, record, recordtriggeredflow

Can we check the field value of the parent record field in formula evaluates to true on insert of a record in flow fast field update. Like record.parent.somefield =='abc'

Answer (score 1):

You can't get a parent value in the entry criteria of the record triggered flow but you can get the parent value in a formula within the flow, something like this works:

```
{!$Record.Account.Owner.FirstName}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!! I tried it in Account flow, I was able to check parent account field in formula evaluates to true expression in entry criteria {!Record.Parent.fieldName}